# Android studio "Could not find method implementation() for arguments"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ocr

I'm very new to Android studio and Gradle so please be specific with your suggestions.

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) git repository because I needed a template of an app with OCR integrated into it. The project was built in Eclipse so I used the Android Studio Import tool to convert it to an Android Studio project. After attempting to build the project and resolving the first few errors by clicking on the links inside the errors, I got the "Could not find method implementation()" error which I can't seem to resolve.
**NOTE - I installed Android Studio just today so I have everything updated.**
This is what my build.gradle file looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this

```
implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.0.0'
```

in build.gradle `app` file under dependencies instead of build.gradle `project` file.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.0.0'
    //...
}
```

Comment: I already have that line no? If not could you be more specific to which file you're referring?

Comment: there are two gradle files, one is for project and another one is for app so you are adding this in project file but you need to use the other one. i.e app file

Comment: It worked! So simple yet I sat for over an hour on this before deciding to ask about it. Thanks a lot and also for the fastest reply I ever got haha. (now to move on to the manifest merger failure :P)

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding :)